# Dynamic function call (apply)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dynamically call a function inside of an object. Found the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function but not fully understanding it. Check out the code below, by triggering `Test.checkQueue()` it should in turn call `showSomething` "method". Thanks.

```
var Test = {    
    , queue : [{action:'showSomething', id:'1234'},{action:'showOther', id:'456'}]
    , showSomething: function(what) {
        alert(what);    
    }
    , checkQueue : function() {
        console.log('checkQueue');
        console.log(this.queue);
        if (this.queue.length) {
            var do = this.queue.shift();
            console.log(do);
            // action.action(action.id);
            do.action.apply(this, do.id || []);
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Keep in mind also that `do` is a *reserved word*.

Comment: The comma preceding `queue` is bad/sloppy syntax and it probably breaks IE.

Comment: 'do' changed. Don't worry about the comma Justin this was an excerpt. One of the reasons I prefer commas at the start of a line - easier to notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) two problems with your use of `apply` here.

1. It is a method of a function object, and you seem to be calling it on strings
2. It always takes an array as its second parameter -- you are passing in either a string or an empty array.

Try calling it like this:

```
Test[do.action].apply(this, do.id ? [do.id] : []);
```

Using `Test[do.action]` will access the actual function, rather than the string "showSomething" or "showOther", and `do.id ? [do.id] : []` will always return an array.

Comment: Alternatively, the OP could use `call` instead of `apply` to avoid the array issue

Comment: Actually you don't need `apply` nor `call`, since the function call is being made on an object instance (`Test`), the context (the `this` keyword) will be set *implicitly* on that function, there is no need to set it *explicitly*, eg. `Test[obj.action](obj.id);`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `do.action` is a string, not a function. You could change your code in one of two ways.

1. Instead of storing the *name* of the function in your queue, actually store the function:

   ```
   queue : [ { action: this.showSomething ...
   ```

   You might need to make sure that it has been defined first or something like that, though.
2. Resolve the string back to the actual property:

   ```
   this[do.action].apply(...)
   ```

Comment: Appreciate the help, I am accepting the first post but I might also use your "this", so I don't have to hard code the "class" name.